# How to turn off line wrap when opening from terminal

Tags: term, bash, wrapping

I'm trying to open a file from terminal and ensure that line-wrap will be off. I'm trying the following code, but it won't work

```
emacs --no-window-system --eval '(setq truncate-lines 1)' file
```

I don't want to set it as default or to change init. Just to open this specific file without wraping lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`truncate-lines` is buffer-local.  To set the `default` for all buffers, use `(setq-default truncate-lines t)`.  Major-modes and minor-modes can reset this variable and it will be necessary to use a major-mode or minor-mode hook in that case, or directory-local variables, or file-local variables.

**EXAMPLE** [assumes we want to load a file with an extension of `el`, which will default to the `emacs-lisp-mode`]:

`/path/to/emacs --no-window-system --eval "(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda nil (setq truncate-lines t)))" /path/to/file.el`

When the file loads, check the value with `M-x describe-variable RET truncate-lines RET` or `C-h v`.

---

**EDIT**:  In the commentary below, the O.P. has indicted that certain files may be opened in `fundamental-mode` because a particular file extension may not be associated with a major-mode.  While it is possible to use file-local variables or directory-local variables, the O.P. has expressed a preference to handle this entirely on the command-line.  One way to accomplish that is as follows:

`/path/to/emacs --no-window-system --eval "(progn (find-file \"/path/to/file.csv\") (setq truncate-lines t))"`

NOTE:  `find-file` (with its underlying functions) set the buffer of the newly opened file as the `current-buffer`.  When `(setq truncate-lines t)` is called subsequent to `(find-file ...)`, it is applied to said `current-buffer`.  If the target buffer did not have focus for whatever the reason (e.g., `find-file-noselect`), then it would be necessary to use something like `(with-current-buffer ...)` to ensure that `truncate-lines` is applied to the correct buffer.

Comment: [The O.P. has indicated briefly in a comment that was withdrawn that he/she wishes to open a file with a **csv** extension.  My comment is in relation thereto.]  A **csv** file extension is not associated with a recognized major-mode using Emacs without any configuration whatsoever.  Would the O.P. prefer a file with a **csv** extension to be in any particular major-mode when the file gets opened in Emacs?   Or, do you prefer `fundamental-mode`?  If you prefer `fundamental-mode`, then you could use `/path/to/emacs --no-window-system --eval "(setq-default truncate-lines t)" /path/to/file.csv`

Comment: The file opens in `Fundamental` mode, so I cannot use hooks. I'm trying to figure out some way of doing it. If you know, please help.

Comment: If you don't mind using `(setq-default ...)`, then the example in the previous comment does the job.  Otherwise, consider using file-local or directory-local variables ...

Comment: The problem is that the code will run in a server by a lot of different users and I don't want my code to be invasive and change their emacs defaults

Comment: How about wrapping your `find-file` function inside the function that sets the `truncate-lines` variable?  `/path/to/emacs --no-window-system --eval "(progn (find-file \"/path/to/file.csv\") (setq truncate-lines t))"`  This example assumes that the target buffer is set by `find-file` so that `truncate-lines` is set locally in that buffer which has focus.  Depending upon the complexity of the function being run, we could use `(with-current-buffer ....)`

Comment: It worked like a charm! Perfect, thank you! This improved A LOT the user experience of my code.